# How to express four white spaces in tr?

Tags: pattern-matching, newline, whitespace

I want to replace newline with four white spaces.

```
tr  "\n"  "    "
```

It is verified that  `tr  "\n"  "    "` can't do .

```
ls -a  |tr  "\n"  "    "
.sane .shutter .ssh .subversion .svx .svy .svz .swa .swb .swc .swd .swe
```

No four white spaces here.

**1.** `\n` works really.
 **2.** no difference between two whitespaces and four whitespaces.

[image]

**3.**`\n` and `\r\n` have same effect.

[image]

Comment: `tr  "\n"  "    "` can do it. The problem is your `ls -a`

Comment: The focus here is  why   `tr "\n" "  "` = `tr "\n" "   "` ?four whitespaces =two whitespaces in tr command?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature Because tr maps single characters onto single characters, not onto strings. \r to space, \n to space. You are using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong tool. `tr` maps single characters onto single characters, not onto strings. From the tr(1) manual page:

> [...] the characters in *string1* are translated into
>        the characters in *string2* where the first character in *string1* is
>        translated into the first character in *string2* and so on.  If *string1* is
>        longer than *string2*, the last character found in *string2* is duplicated
>        until *string1* is exhausted.

You want a more general pattern matcher and replacer:

```
ls | perl -p -e 's/\n/    /'
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1.   Understanding the behavior of `tr` command:

Reviewing the manual of `tr` command, it states that:

> NAME
>
> tr - translate or delete characters
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]
> ```

Where:

> `SET`s are specified as **strings of characters**

So every character in the first list (`SET1`) will be changed by their counterparts in the second list (`SET2`)

if we have a file named "**file**" containing:

```
wordorwd
```

by executing this command:

```
tr 'word' 'abcd' < file
```

we will get `abcdbcad`

For more about `tr` command you can check this [link](http://www.linfo.org/tr.html)

## 2.   Understanding the output format of `ls` command:

To understand the output of command `ls`. We need to see how it works internally. You can get it by downloading the package `coreutils`:

```
git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils
```

Or check it directly via this link: [ls-source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c).

**In general it searches first the directory and then fetches for all its related files, sort and push them in a linked list after that it pops and deliver them in the output stream after appending "`\n`".**

There is also a linux command called `od` that can show the output of `ls` command:

```
ls -a | od -c
```

---

Now the `ls -a | tr  "\n" "   "` is actually working fine and is changing the newline into a space which leads to get as a display a **1** **only line** containg all the file names separated by spaces.

For `ls -a | tr "\r\n" "  "` there is no carriage return  in `ls` output only the newline will be changed and that's what explains the same behavior.

You can use `-d` option of `tr` command to confirm that **by deleting first the carriage return (No effect) and then the newline**

```
ls -a | tr -d "\r"
ls -a | tr -d "\n"
```